# Loading a script with $().load() method. Why can't I see it in Chrome Developer Tools Sources tab?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I'm loading a script with this bit of code

```
 $('#taskScript').load(scriptName, function (data, textStatus, xmlHttpRequest) {
```

into this empty script tag in my file

```
 <script id="taskScript"></script>
```

I would like to debug the script, but I can't see it in the sources tab in CDT.

Comment: This seems to be a shortcoming in the chrome devtools. Although this is a very rare way of loading scripts. If someone asked if this works I wouldn't even be sure.

Answer (score 0):

That's not what the `.load()` API is for.  I think you want `$.getScript()` instead. That will fetch your script and execute it. You don't need an empty `<script>` tag, just:

```
$.getScript( yourURL, function(theScript, status, jqxhr) {
  // called on success after script has run
});
```